# Trouble with changing variables from the new iOS 16 App Intents

Tags: swiftui, ios16, app-shortcut

I have scaled down one of the Apps I am working on to use to learn how to program App Intents and utilize Siri in my apps. I will post the scaled-down version of my code below in its simplest form. This is a simple app that merely keeps a total in an `@State var` named `counter`. The app shows the current total along with 2 buttons, one button being labeled "minus" and the other labeled "add".

When someone taps the minus button, 1 is subtracted from `counter` if `counter` is greater than 0. When someone taps the plus button, 1 is added to `counter` as long as it is not greater than 10,000.

The buttons actually call functions called `decrementCounter` and `incrementCounter` which do the math and update the value of the state variable `counter`.

The app works just fine as is. Minus and plus buttons work and the view is updated to reflect the current value of `counter` as buttons are pushed.

The problem is when I try to use an App Intent to add or subtract from `counter`. In this example, I only put in two App Intents, one to add to `counter` and the other to have Siri tell you what the current value of `counter` is.

The app intent called `SiriAddOne` calls the same function as is used when a button is pressed, however, `counter` does not get incremented.

Also, the app intent `SiriHowMany` will always tell you the counter is zero.

It's like the App Intents are not able to access the `counter` variable used in the view.

I do know that the functions are being called because, in my main program where I extracted this from, the `incrementCounter` and `decrementCounter` functions do others things as well. Those other things all work when I use the App Intent to call the function, but the `counter` variable remains unchanged.

Hopefully, someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here or how I need to go about doing this correctly. Thank you.

```
import SwiftUI
import AppIntents

struct ContentView: View {

// This variable counter is the only thing that changes
// and should be what forces the view to update

@State var counter = 0    

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()

            Text("Total")

            // Displays the current value of the counter
            Text(String(counter))

            Spacer()

            // When button is pressed call decrementCounter function
            Button(action: {
                decrementCounter()
            }, label: {
                Text("Minus")
            })

            Spacer()

            // When button is pressed call incrementCounter function
            Button(action: {
                incrementCounter()
            }, label: {
                Text("Add")
            })

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }

    
    // subtract 1 from the counter
    // when this happens the view should update to
    // to reflect the new value.

    func decrementCounter() {
        if counter > 0 {
            counter -= 1
        }
        return
    }

    // Add 1 to the counter
    // when this happens the view should update to
    // to reflect the new value.

    func incrementCounter() {
        if counter <= 9999 {
            counter += 1
        }
        return
    }

   
    // Set up App Intent, perform action when matched
    // and have siri state it has been done.

    @available(iOS 16, *)
    struct SiriAddOne: AppIntent {
        static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Add 1"
        static var description = IntentDescription("Adds 1 to the counter")

        @MainActor
        func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
            ContentView().incrementCounter()
            return .result(dialog: "Okay, added 1 to counter.")
            }
        }

    // Set up App Intent, perform action when matched
    // and have siri state the current value of the counter.

    @available(iOS 16, *)
    struct SiriHowMany: AppIntent {
        static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "How Many"
        static var description = IntentDescription("How Many?")

        func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
            return .result(dialog: "You have  \(ContentView().counter).")
            }
        }

    // Defines the two shortcut phrases to be used to call the two AppIntents
    @available(iOS 16, *)
    struct SiriAppShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
        static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
            AppShortcut(
                intent: SiriAddOne(),
                phrases: ["Add one to \(.applicationName)"]
            )
            AppShortcut(
                intent: SiriHowMany(),
                phrases: ["How many \(.applicationName)"]
            )
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        ContentView()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ContentView().incrementCounter()`

When you do `ContentView()`, you're creating a new `ContentView` object, which has a separate counter from the main `ContentView` created by your app.

I'd recommend moving the counter to a class conforming to the `ObservableObject` protocol. Make only one instance of it and store that instance in a global variable, then add an `@ObservedObject` property to `ContentView` whose value is that object. For example:

```swift
class CounterData: ObservableObject {
    var counter = 0
}
let counterData = CounterData()

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject let myCounterData = counterData

    func incrementCounter() {
        if myCounterData.counter <= 9999 {
            myCounterData.counter += 1
        }
    }

    @available(iOS 16, *)
    struct SiriHowMany: AppIntent {
        static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "How Many"
        static var description = IntentDescription("How Many?")

        func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
            return .result(dialog: "You have \(counterData.counter).")
        }
    }

    /* other code skipped for brevity */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I posted this like 6 months ago and finally got it working and your answer was spot on.  Thank you!